# Ubuntu installed Grub2 into my Windows EFI System Partition - Is this an issue and if so how should I remove it

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, boot

I am new to Linux and was installing Ubuntu Desktop 18.04 LTS onto a separate drive to my Windows one. I installed by booting to a USB in UEFI mode and running the Ubuntu installer. I followed tutorials on how to set up the drive partitions for a Linux installation however I made a mistake and forgot to create a separate EFI System Partition on the Linux drive. The installation worked completely fine and Ubuntu runs without issue, when I boot the computer Grub2 is automatically loaded and allows me to boot to either Windows or Ubuntu however the Grub2 runs off my Windows drive.

I was hoping to install Ubuntu and all required components to a separate drive and not touch my Windows drive at all. My question is if there is any foreseeable problem with Grub2 being installed along side my Windows boot manager in the EFI System Partition and if so is there a way to completely remove it from this drive or restore the partition to a Windows default?

If I am wrong with any of my understanding of what has happened any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

**The ESP (EFI System Partition) is NOT "Windows EFI", this partition is for ALL installed OSes in a multi-boot setup.**

So, yes, everything happened as it is supposed to happen. You can have more than one ESP, in different drives, but that is neither necessary nor recommended.

Comment: Sorry for the very late reply but thank you very much for the answer. I have left the system as you said it should be with one ESP.